# Two CSR files with same information from different Servers

Tags: ssl-certificate, csr

I have two web servers(IIS) Prod/DR and I am required to install a certificate with same common name on both the servers.

I have generated two CSR files from these two servers with same information (common name, location etc)

We are required to generate a third party signed certificate, but I am confused/ignorant when it asks for CSR. These two CSR files when I compared are different(byte compared).

Should I just upload any 1 of the CSR file and use the cert generated to be installed on both servers? Will both server accept this certificate (after in pending cert request state) generated with same information but has different CSR files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a better fit for something like server fault, but I'll give it a shot:

A CSR is a unique per private key.  You need to pick *one* CSR, and request it from your CA.  Your CA will respond with the full certificate, which can be exported from the machine on which you issued the CSR and imported to the other servers.

If you were to request multiple CSR's be fulfilled, you would get multiple certificates.  Instead, you need to complete the process once and copy the returned certificate.

See http://www.sslshopper.com/move-or-copy-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-windows-server-to-another-windows-server.html for step by step instructions.